# Put ENTRYPOINT and CMD in Supervisor

Tags: docker, supervisord

I am trying to set up an image with two commands:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/bin/wait-mysql"]
CMD ["runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

I want to put them in supervisor config file to execute with other commands. This is the command I have in config:

```
[program:weblate]
user=weblate
command=/app/bin/wait-mysql runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
redirect_stderr=true
```

In my understanding, when ENTRYPOINT and CMD are present in Dockerfile, CMD is appended to Entrypoint. So why is my command is not working? Whenever I have Entrypoint or CMD separately, they are working in Supervisor, but not together.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint

Comment: I read the documentation. That is why I appended them together in supervisor, but still not working